# Cocoapods is not installing/working correctly on MacOS Monterey

Tags: ios, macos, cocoapods, homebrew, macos-monterey

I am trying to install cocoapods but at first I was not able to do it via `sudo gem install cocoapods` because of some "`FilePermission`" Error.

Then I tried it using homebrew, it got installed but it does not work.

It gives me following error:
`zsh: command not found: cocoapods`

and when I use "pod --version" as mentioned, I get following logs:

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1411:in `rescue in block in activate_dependencies': Could not find 'minitest' (>= 5.1) among 40 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/shubhamojha/.local/share/gem/ruby/2.6.0:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0:/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec' at: /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/specifications/activesupport-6.1.5.gemspec, execute `gem env` for more information
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1408:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1397:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1397:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1379:in `activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1415:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1397:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1397:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1379:in `activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1415:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1397:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1397:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1379:in `activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:286:in `block in activate_bin_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:285:in `synchronize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:285:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Never show us pictures of code, please.

Comment: @matt I have removed the image.

Comment: The fact that we are seeing Library/Ruby/ or that you are having to say `sudo` is a total bug. You need to use a user-installed ruby.

Answer (score -1):

Basically ***Cocoapods*** use **pod** key word to perform its command use:

```
pod --version
```

to check the version of **Cocoapods** on your mac.

Comment: Even the pod version is throwing following error: /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1411:in `rescue in block in activate_dependencies': Could not find 'minitest' (>= 5.1) among 40 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/shubhamojha/.local/share/gem/ruby/2.6.0:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0:/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec' at: /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/specifications/activesupport-6.1.5.gemspec, execute `gem env` for more information